# Событие начало/завершение перетаскивания маркера на карте

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Добрый день. Как отловить начало перемещения маркера и когда пользователь отпустил маркер на карте?

Конкретная задача:
По GPS/NETWORK идет определение "грязных" координат, и пользователь затем вручную подтаскивает чуть маркер до нужного места, после чего, когда пользователь отпустит маркер, мне нужно зафиксировать эти координаты.

Но событий у маркера я не нашел. Может они есть у  какого-то спец. объекта?

Comment: Подозреваю что нужно обрабатывать Touch Event и по нажатию/отпусканию пальца фиксировать положение. Но может я заблуждаюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос, вдруг кому пригодится. У карты есть специальный слушатель

```
map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

    }
});
```